# Detecting and restarting my crashed .NET application

Tags: .net

How can I detect that my .NET application has crashed, and then restart it?

Comment: I found some solutions to this question (before I asked it), so I thought it would be nice to have the answers in SO. If you have additional answers, please be my guest. Or just vote the best answer to guide others. Also please retag this question as you deem appropriate.

Comment: Added info about restarting a console app, as this is apparently what you're using.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another solution (based on [this example](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/08/30/4366.aspx)) is to create a launcher that controls the application:

```
class LauncherProgram
{
    static int count = 3;

    static void Main()
    {
        Launch();
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    static void Launch()
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "MyApp.exe";
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Exited += LaunchIfCrashed;
        process.Start();
    }

    static void LaunchIfCrashed(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process process = (Process) o;
        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            if (count-- > 0) // restart at max count times
                Launch();
            else
                Environment.Exit(process.ExitCode);
        }
        else
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only possible upgrade would be to make the "watchdog" a windows service.

Comment: better to add some timestamp code and detect if the app crashed on startup

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help with that one, @AshK. Sorry.

Comment: Add process.start();

Answer (score 8):

If this is a Windows Forms app:

- Set **jitDebugging = true** in App.Config. This prevents the built-in Windows Forms unhandled exception handler being triggered.

Now regardless of whether this is a Windows Forms app or a console app:

- Register for the **Application.ThreadException** event, e.g. in C#:

  Application.ThreadException += new Threading.ThreadExceptionHandler(CatchFatalException);

At this point, your app is already on its way into a black hole. What happens next depends on whether or not this is a Windows Forms app:

- If it's a Windows Forms app, call the [Application.Restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart.aspx) method in your **CatchFatalException** event handler.
- Otherwise you will instead need to p/invoke to the [application restart and recovery](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/11/11/Windows-Vista-Application-Recovery-with-C_2300_.aspx) native functions. That link discusses Vista, but in my tests it works just fine on XP as well.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible for a console application to do something similar to `Application.ThreadException += MyHandler;`?

Comment: Yes, a console app can do the same.

Comment: But it does not have access to the Application class, does it?

Comment: It does have access to the Application class if you add the correct namespace. But in my test, I see an "Unsupported" exception, so you're right, this doesn't work for Console apps. I will change my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

- run the work inside an AppDomain; use the primary AppDomain to monitor it (doesn't guard against process kill, though)
- lots of exception handling! i.e. don't let a fatal error tear down the process
- run it in something that already has recycling built in - IIS for example

Comment: Thanks Marc. Could you please add an example on how to implement the AppDomain-based solution you suggest?

Comment: Assuming this is a Windows Forms or console app, you can use Application.Restart - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to create another process to monitor your application, and restart it if it is terminated:

```
class ProcessMonitorProgram
{
    const string myProcess = "MyApp.exe";

    static void Main()
    {
        new Timer(CheckProcess, null, 0, 60 * 1000);
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    static void CheckProcess(object obj)
    {
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(myProcess).Length == 0)
            Process.Start(myProcess);
    }
}
```

One of the problems with this solution is that it will keep the process restarting forever, until this monitoring application itself is terminated.